# Switching view from gluon CharmListView works on Desktop but not in Android

Tags: java, android, gluon, gluon-mobile

So I have been working on a project and I have a CharmListView that populates with the name of the task to be used.  I can login through my login screen, get to the CharmListView and click on the task I want to have open.  It opens on the Desktop when I am testing it, but in Android it fails, saying the location is not found, and that:
    `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View.setName(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Here are my charm classes that I have:

This one is the task model essentially.

```
public class CharmHomeNavTask {
private String taskName;
private String taskDesc;

private static final Image IMAGE_ADMIN = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/admin.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_AUDIT_TOOL = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/auditTool.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_CONSOLIDATE_PACKAGE = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/consolidatePackage.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_DISPOSAL = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/disposal.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_EQUIP_MANGAGE = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/equipmentManagement.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_INTRA_TRANSFER = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/intratransfer.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_PICKUP = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/pickup.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_TRU_WASTE_PREP = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/truWastePrep.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_VISUAL_INSPECTION = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/visualInspection.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_WALL2WALL = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/wall2wall.png"));
private static final Image IMAGE_WASTE_ID = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/gov/lanl/taskImages/wasteIdentification.png"));

private static Image[] listOfImages = {IMAGE_WASTE_ID, IMAGE_VISUAL_INSPECTION, IMAGE_TRU_WASTE_PREP, IMAGE_CONSOLIDATE_PACKAGE, IMAGE_INTRA_TRANSFER, IMAGE_PICKUP, IMAGE_DISPOSAL, IMAGE_ADMIN, IMAGE_WALL2WALL,
        IMAGE_EQUIP_MANGAGE, IMAGE_AUDIT_TOOL };

public CharmHomeNavTask(String taskName, String taskDesc){
    this.taskName = taskName;
    this.taskDesc = taskDesc;
}

public String getTaskName() {
    return taskName;
}

public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}

public String getTaskDesc() {
    return taskDesc;
}

public void setTaskDesc(String taskDesc) {
    this.taskDesc = taskDesc;
}

public static void setListOfImages(Image[] listOfImages) {
    listOfImages = listOfImages;
}

public static Image[] getListOfImages(){
    return listOfImages;
}

public static Image getSingleImageFromList(int index){
    return listOfImages[index];
}
}
```

This one is the creation of the tasks into an ObservableList

```
public class CharmHomeNavTasks {


public static ObservableList<CharmHomeNavTask> tasksList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new CharmHomeNavTask("Waste Identification", "Identify you waste from this screen."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("TRU Visual Inspection", "Visual Inspection of TRU waste."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("TRU Drum Preparation", "Prepare your TRU drums here."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("Consolidation/Packaging", "Consolidate and package your waste."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("Intra-Facility Transfer", "Transferring of waste within the same facility."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("Inter-Facility Pickup", "Picking up waste within the same facility."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("Disposal Tasks", "Disposal of waste tasks."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("Administrative Tasks", "Administrators have special tasks they can perform here."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("Wall-Wall Inventory", "Wall to Wall inventory tasks."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("Equipment Management", "Waste related equipment tasks."),
        new CharmHomeNavTask("Audit Support Tool", "Tool for audit related tasks."));

public static ObservableList<CharmHomeNavTask> getTasksList() {
    return tasksList;
}
}
```

This is the one that is giving me trouble because I have my onMouseClicked event here and I set the item(or task) to selected.  This seems to work fine even on Android as I can the the system to tell me which item was clicked.

```
public class CharmHomeNavTaskCell extends CharmListCell<CharmHomeNavTask> {

private final ListTile tile;
private final ImageView imageView;
private CharmHomeNavTask item;
public CharmHomeNavTask carryOverItem;


public CharmHomeNavTaskCell(CharmListView listView){
    tile = new ListTile();
    imageView = new ImageView();
    tile.setPrimaryGraphic(imageView);
    carryOverItem = item;
    tile.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        System.out.println("*******************  Item clicked " + item.getTaskName());
        listView.setSelectedItem(item);
    });
    setText(null);
}

@Override
public void updateItem(CharmHomeNavTask item, boolean empty){
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    this.item = item;
    imageView.setFitWidth(32);
    imageView.setFitHeight(32);
    if (item != null && !empty) {
        tile.textProperty().setAll(item.getTaskName() + " ", item.getTaskDesc());
        tile.setWrapText(true);
        final Image[] image = CharmHomeNavTask.getListOfImages();

            super.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
            switch (item.getTaskName()) {
                case "Waste Identification":
                    imageView.setImage(image[0]);
                    break;
                case "TRU Visual Inspection":
                    imageView.setImage(image[1]);
                    break;
                case "TRU Drum Preparation":
                    imageView.setImage(image[2]);
                    break;
                case "Consolidation/Packaging":
                    imageView.setImage(image[3]);
                    break;
                case "Intra-Facility Transfer":
                    imageView.setImage(image[4]);
                    break;
                case "Inter-Facility Pickup":
                    imageView.setImage(image[5]);
                    break;
                case "Disposal Tasks":
                    imageView.setImage(image[6]);
                    break;
                case "Administrative Tasks":
                    imageView.setImage(image[7]);
                    break;
                case "Wall-Wall Inventory":
                    imageView.setImage(image[8]);
                    break;
                case "Equipment Management":
                    imageView.setImage(image[9]);
                    break;
                case "Audit Support Tool":
                    imageView.setImage(image[10]);
                    break;
            }
            setGraphic(tile);
    } else {
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the AppViewManager Class.  I am using Glisten and Afterburner just so that you know.

```
public class AppViewManager {

private static String getLoggedInUser(User user){
    if (user != null) {
        return user.getId();
    } else {
        return "Not Logged In";
    }
}

public static final AppViewRegistry REGISTRY = new AppViewRegistry();

public static final AppView PRIMARY_VIEW = view("Home", PrimaryPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.HOME, SHOW_IN_DRAWER, HOME_VIEW);
public static final AppView SECONDARY_VIEW = view("Task List", SecondaryPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.LIST, SHOW_IN_DRAWER);
public static final AppView SETTINGS_VIEW = view("Settings", SettingsView.class, MaterialDesignIcon.SETTINGS_APPLICATIONS, SHOW_IN_DRAWER);
public static final AppView INTRAFACILITYTRANSFER_VIEW = view("Intra-Facility Transfer", IntraFacilityView.class, MaterialDesignIcon.EDIT_LOCATION);


private static AppView view(String title, Class<? extends GluonPresenter<?>> presenterClass, MaterialDesignIcon menuIcon, AppView.Flag... flags ) {
    return REGISTRY.createView(name(presenterClass), title, presenterClass, menuIcon, flags);
}

private static String name(Class<? extends GluonPresenter<?>> presenterClass) {
    return presenterClass.getSimpleName().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT).replace("PRESENTER", "");
}

public static void registerViewsAndDrawer(MobileApplication app) {
    for (AppView view : REGISTRY.getViews()) {
        view.registerView(app);
    }

    Image image = new Image(WcatsAndroidDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png"));


    NavigationDrawer.Header header = new NavigationDrawer.Header("\nWCATS" + "- " + getLoggedInUser(WcatsAndroidDemo.getInstance().getLoggedUser()),
            "Waste Management System", new ImageView(image));

    // TODO: Add a footer to the drawer that contains settings, help & feedback, and About

    NavigationDrawer.Footer footer = new NavigationDrawer.Footer("No tasks currently need to be synchronized.", null);

    //Create the sub items for the drawer
    NavigationDrawer.Item about = new NavigationDrawer.Item("About", MaterialDesignIcon.INFO.graphic());
    NavigationDrawer.Item logOut = new NavigationDrawer.Item("Logout", MaterialDesignIcon.EXIT_TO_APP.graphic());
    // TODO: make the rest of the submenu items that go in the header.
    DefaultDrawerManager drawerManager = new DefaultDrawerManager(app, header, REGISTRY.getViews()) {
        {

            NavigationDrawer drawer = getDrawer();
            drawer.visibleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue){
                    header.setTitle("\nWCATS - " + getLoggedInUser(WcatsAndroidDemo.getInstance().getLoggedUser()));
                }
            });
            // Add items
            drawer.setFooter(footer);
            footer.setStyle("-fx-text-size: 6");
            drawer.getItems().addAll(new Separator(), about, logOut, new Separator());
            // TODO: provide action based on item selected
            drawer.selectedItemProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if(newValue.equals(about)) {
                    System.out.println("test");
                } else if (newValue.equals(logOut)){
                    WcatsAndroidDemo.getInstance().userLogout();
                } else if (newValue.equals(SECONDARY_VIEW.getMenuItem())){
                    if (getLoggedInUser(WcatsAndroidDemo.getInstance().getLoggedUser()).equals("Not Logged In")) {
                        AppViewManager.PRIMARY_VIEW.switchView();
                    } else {
                        AppViewManager.SECONDARY_VIEW.switchView();
                    }
                }
            } ));

        }

    };
    drawerManager.installDrawer();
}
}
```

Lastly, here is the Presenter class for the view that I am navigation from and want to go to the task that is selected.

```
public class SecondaryPresenter extends GluonPresenter<WcatsAndroidDemo> {

@FXML
private View homeView;

@FXML
public CharmListView<CharmHomeNavTask, Integer> charmListView;

public void initialize() {
    homeView.setShowTransitionFactory(BounceInRightTransition::new);

    AppBar appBar = getApp().getAppBar();
    homeView.showingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> getApp().showLayer(DRAWER_LAYER)));
        appBar.setTitleText("Task Selection");
    });
    charmListView.setFloatingHeaderVisible(false);
    charmListView.setItems(CharmHomeNavTasks.getTasksList());
    charmListView.setCellFactory(param -> new CharmHomeNavTaskCell(charmListView));
    charmListView.selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue.getTaskName().equals("Intra-Facility Transfer")){
            AppViewManager.INTRAFACILITYTRANSFER_VIEW.switchView(ViewStackPolicy.SKIP);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Just in case you do need it to figure anything out here is the view that I am trying to navigate to.

```
public class IntraFacilityView extends GluonPresenter<WcatsAndroidDemo> {

@FXML
public ChoiceBox facilityCMBox;
@FXML
public ChoiceBox storageUnitOrgCMBox;
@FXML
public ChoiceBox storageUnitDestCMBox;
@FXML
public ChoiceBox gridXCMBox;
@FXML
public ChoiceBox gridYCMBox;
@FXML
public ChoiceBox gridZCMBox;
@FXML
public CheckBox organizeUnitCHKBox;

@FXML
public Button viewMoreReqsBTN;
@FXML
public Button viewPendingMovesBTN;
@FXML
public Button resumeTaskBTN;

@FXML
private View intrafacility;


public void initialize(){
    intrafacility.setShowTransitionFactory(BounceInRightTransition::new);
    intrafacility.showingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            AppBar appBar = getApp().getAppBar();
            appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> {
                getApp().showLayer(DRAWER_LAYER);
            }));

            appBar.setTitleText("Intra-Facility Transfer");
            appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.CLOSE.button(e -> {
                AppViewManager.SECONDARY_VIEW.switchView();
            }));
        }
    });

}

public void handleOrganizeUnitsCHKBox(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
}

public void handleViewMoreReqs(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
}

public void handleResumeTask(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
}

public void handlevVewPendingMoves(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
}
}
```

I know that some Android devices are not the best with JavaFxPorts, but I haven't seen anything about Panasonic toughpads having known issues like Samsung.  I did have to do some janky stuff to get the abdroid devices to register the touches as clicks, but that seems to be working fine now.

This has me as a standstill as I can not figure out why Android can not find the location but it works fine on the desktop.

Here is the file structure:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtR19.png)

Comment: Try using full lower case names in the FXML files

Comment: @JoséPereda I will give that a try and get back on whether that solved the issue or not.

Comment: @JoséPereda  That solved the issue.  Thanks